# Automatically purge last 10 images posted in Discord (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a system for my bot in discord that'll purge the last 10 images posted & uploaded (links & uploads) in the chat, does anyone know how I can go about coding this? This was my idea (sort of)

```
if (message.channel.type == 'general') {
    if (*the last 10 messages that have been sent are images*) {
         message.delete(); // delete last 10 images
    }
}
```

Comment: You would want to select the last 10 messages, loop over them, check each message whether it's an image or not, and then act accordingly

Comment: look at [MessageAttachment.height](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=height) to check if the message is an image and follow the logic in the first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`fetchMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) method to retrieve a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that consists of a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of the the last 10 [messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), by setting the `limit` to 10 using the [ChannelLogsQueryOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions).

Using this collection of messages, as @Chris Satchell mentioned in the comments you loop through it and check if [`message.attatchments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) is present for all of messages. Alternatively you can check if the `<Collection>.size` of the `attachments` for the entire collection of messages is equivalent to 10, and if it does you can go ahead with the next step.

Now that you have a collection of messages that you would like to delete, simply pass this collection into the `messages` parameter of the method [`bulkDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete).

So as a result, you fetch the last 10 messages in a [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel), and then check the `attachments` property of the fetched collection of messages and then call the `bulkDelete` method on this collection.