# Purging only images not messages

Tags: discord.js

Is there a way to purge/clear ONLY images. I know how to purge regular messages. But I want to know how to clear images. I’m having a hard time figure this out.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865413/) answer your question?

Comment: @Jakye kind of? I want to delete ALL images not just 10 though. And it probably does answer my question, I just don’t understand.